# PHP MySQL if row exists not doing anything

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get this piece of code to check if the line already exists in the database.

These lines get inserted into the database:

```
512150 # Merlinz is banned permanently by SO_Conner. # banned untill never for RDM
```

Now this piece of code checks if it already exists in the DB, if it doesn't exist we insert it.

```
    $search = "permanently"; 
$logfile = "ban_list.txt";
$timestamp = time();
// Read from file 
$file = fopen($logfile, "r");
?> <head> <title>Searching: <?php echo $search ?></title> </head> <?php
while( ($line =  fgets($file) )!= false)
{
if(stristr($line,$search))
{
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pincodes` WHERE `Pincode` = '$pincode' ");   
if(mysql_num_rows($check) == 1) {
die();                                                                                          }
else
{
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if(stristr($line,$search))

$sql = "INSERT INTO `ingamebanlist` (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('$line', '$timestamp')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
// case insensitive
echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>";
}   
}
```

Like I said, it is still inserting it into my Database even though the line is present in the database.

Thanks                                                      }

Comment: I can't see this working at all, while you're mixing MySQL APIs. Not with `$check = mysql_query("SELECT...` anyway, and `$conn = new mysqli(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($check)>0) {
  echo " ";                                                                                         
 }
  else
  {
```

change your line of code to this,
this would check if it already exist.
*Flies Away*

Comment: Oh, it is for checking the lines.

Comment: @user4491831 and please use this and put in in the top of your code where you would like to use and execute when the submit button is pressed. so your compiler would know where to start
    if(isset['submitbuttonname']) {
    }

Comment: This script has to activate on script access.

Comment: @MarkYu Just to make it clear, php isn't a compiled language! Also OP is mixing MYsql API's and OP is executing querys without a connection at the top

Answer (score -1):

Try checking in the following manner

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($check) !== FALSE)
```

Also try printing the query to see how the value is embedding for debugging purpose...

Comment: What is the value of $pincode, how it is populated in the variable?. Also can i see a sample query if possible?

Answer (score -1):

If it's a ban list based on a unique username why not alter the table to make the column unique. This code will also delete duplicates in the column 'Ban'.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE ingamebanlist ADD UNIQUE (Ban);
```

Next, mysql_num_rows() is deprecated in php 5.5

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Your best bet (even if your mysql functions work) is to change the mysql function calls to mysqli function calls. They are more secure and up to date.As well as making sure there is a constant in your code so your not switching between them.

If you change the mysql commands to mysqli this should work.

```
mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
```

Lastly, if you change the 'Ban' column to unique and make use of the mysqli_affected_rows this code should be all you need to insert when doesn't exist.

```
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `ingamebanlist` (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('$line', '$timestamp')");

$num = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);

if($num > 0)
{
echo "Successfully Inserted";
}
else if($num == 0)
{
echo "Line already exists";
}
else
{
echo "Insert Error";
}
```